# to_xml with extra method that returns a hash in Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, xml-serialization

I have a class something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  # .... some stuff

  def prices
    # Make hash like { "Regular" => 10, "Discount" => 8 }
  end
end
```

I grab this from the database and try `to_xml` on it:

```
Product.find(id).to_xml(:methods => [:prices])
```

But if fails at the prices hash

```
... some XML
<prices>Regular10Discount8</prices>
... some more XML
```

`to_json` works as expected.

What's the easiest way to alter the format so it ends up as something like this:

```
<prices>
  <price name="Regular">10</price>
  <price name="Discount">8</price>
</prices>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You're left with doing the `to_xml` formatting Yourself :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  def prices 
    ...
  end

  def to_xml(options = {})
    super(options) do |xml|
      if prices.empty?
        xml.tag! 'prices' # empty tag
      else
        xml.prices do
          prices.each do |name, val|
            xml.price val, 'name' => name
          end
        end
      end
      yield(xml) if block_given?
    end
  end

end
```

than just to a `Product.find(id).to_xml`